# <p> tags storing in database

Tags: php, laravel, tinymce

I have this function to store articles in the database.

```
public function postContents(Request $request)
{
    $content = new Content();
    $content->article = $request->article;
    $content->save();
}
```

But even if `$request->article` is a plain `This is a new article`, it is stored as `<p>This is a new article</p>` in the database.

I have used TinyMCE editor:

```
<textarea name="article" class="myTextEditor" rows="15" cols="96"></textarea>
```

Comment: maybe find a setting wherein it doesn't include paragraph tags, or use a band aid solultion like `striptags`

Comment: can you dd() the $request->article to verify that it is actualy without the tags? I'm guessing the tags are there, but you don't see them as they are interpreted as html code. My guess is they are coming from the editor (tinymce)